# Use .NET assembly without locking dll file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I have a windows service that executes once a day. It's only 10 minutes of action.

I build the service's files in the bin folder of the website, because the service uses the website dll's.

Unfortunately I noticed that when I installed the website module (dotnetnuke .zip module by website installer) I got an error that the file is locked by antoher process.

Disabling the service before each module is installed is very problematic so I want to make my service not lock the dll's which are used in it.

I read about the AppDomain and ShadowCopyFiles options, but I can NOT make them work for me.

This is an example of how I use ShadowCopyFiles:

```
class Program
{
    static string GenerateRandomName()
    {
        //maybe name must be unique?!
        var random = new Random();
        return "a" + random.Next().ToString() + "b" + random.Next();
    }

    static int RandomNumber()
    {
        var info = ConfigureAppDomainSettings();

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(GenerateRandomName(), null, info);
        var assembly = domain.Load("SharedLibrary");
        var shared = (SharedLibrary.IShared)assembly.CreateInstance("SharedLibrary.Shared");

        int retVal = shared.RandomNumber();

        AppDomain.Unload(domain);

        domain = null;
        assembly = null;
        shared = null;
        info = null;

        Console.WriteLine("before cleanning");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("after cleanning");

        return retVal;
    }

    static AppDomainSetup ConfigureAppDomainSettings()
    {
        AppDomainSetup domainSettings = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;
        domainSettings.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
        domainSettings.CachePath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\eshop\DesktopModules\Rossnet_EShop\SharedAssemblyTest\PrivateCache";

        return domainSettings;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Code of example assembly:

```
public interface IShared
{
    int RandomNumber();
}

[Serializable]
public class Shared : IShared
{
    public int RandomNumber()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return random.Next(20);
    }
}
```

A private cache is created and not locked and the original file is locked. <- right now this is absurd for me.

Comment: Your IShared interface gets loaded into both appdomains.  Which puts a permanent lock on the DLL.  Put the Shared class it in another one.

Comment: I cast to dynamic type instead of interface previously and it didn't work, so it isn't the only problem with my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have access to modify all code that uses the assemblies, simply loading them by the [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx)  overload that takes a `byte[]` should do the trick. You'll read the file yourself, and pass it to that method. I use this approach myself (for other reasons though), and it gives me the ability to update the files at any time.

A way of doing this easily (albeit a bit weird) is to rename your files (from .dll to something else, so they can't be found) and then subscribe to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx)  event, which will be called when they're missing, at which point you can have your code that manually loads the assemblies.